# How to create a variable from xarray dataset coordinates?

Tags: python, python-xarray

Based on a xarray dataset containing latitude and longitude coordinates and several variables I would like to create a new variable containing objects based on the latitude and longitude coordinates.

For example, from the following dataset:

```py
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:    (time: 100, x: 1000, y: 840)
Coordinates:
  * x          (x) float64 2.452e+06 2.458e+06 2.462e+06 ... 7.442e+06 7.448e+06
  * y          (y) float64 1.352e+06 1.358e+06 1.362e+06 ... 5.542e+06 5.548e+06
  * time       (time) datetime64[ns] 2015-01-01 ... 2015-01-05T03:00:00
```

... I would like to simply create a point object for each grid cell based on the respective latitude and longitude coordinates.

Pseudocode:

```py
ds['points'] = (('y', 'x'), point_creation_function(ds.y, ds.x))
```

(How) Can I apply a function that requires the coordinate values as inputs such, that the result can be directly added as new variable?

A horrible implementation after an initialization of ds.points would be:

```py
for x_value in ds.x:
    for y_value in ds.y:
        ds.points.loc[dict(x=x_value, y=y_value)] = (x_value, y_value)
```

I assume there is an elegant and computation-efficient solution available, but searching the documentation I did not understand how to use apply, reduce or other functions to achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

If I undestand you question correctly, I think this is the answer:

```
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr

# Create some example data
data = np.random.rand(10,5,6)

# Make the dataset.
ds = xr.Dataset({"my_var": (["time", "x", "y"], data)})

# Create a MultiIndex
ds = ds.stack(points=("x", "y"))
```